# Cron job on Mac not running during sleep

Tags: macos, mac, bash, cron, crontab

I have a cron job that will mail a list of all Google Tasks to my email address daily at 7am. (http://privacylog.blogspot.com/2010/07/api-for-google-tasks.html)

I am running this on my laptop which, like me, is in sleep mode at 7am.

Can I fix this to run after I wake the machine from sleep each day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `launchd` instead of `cron`, tasks that were supposed to have ran while your Mac was sleeping will run when it wakes up. There's some more info (including usage) available [here](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html).

(For what it's worth, Apple recommends using `launchd` instead of `cron`, and may even phase out `cron` at some point in the future.)

Comment: For those who may look here, but are running systems other than OS X, such as Linux, take a look at [anacron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).